# Mysql query does not Update the same record

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I want to Update/Insert some data into MySQL. Here's my code snippet:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import mysql.connector
import datetime

Host_Auction = 'MY_URL/live_data.json'

def Get_Json_From_Url():
        resp = requests.get(url=Host_Auction)
        data = resp.json()
        return data

def Update_Portal(server_data):
        """ Connect to MySQL database """
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(host=DBhost,database=DBname,user=DBusername,password=DBpassword)

        cursor = conn.cursor()
        ##Update Prices on portal
        for index in server_data:
          query = """UPDATE tblproducts 
                     SET updated_at  = %s                     
                     WHERE gid=21 AND configoption1 like '%auction%' AND configoption2 like %s """

          query_data =(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%d"),"%"+str(index['key'])+"%")          
          cursor.execute(query, query_data)
          conn.commit()


          print ("Update: ", cursor.rowcount, index['key'])
          if (cursor.rowcount == 0):
              cursor = conn.cursor()
              query= """INSERT INTO `tblproducts`
                        VALUES (null,'server',21,%s,%s,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,'recurring',0,'','','',0,
                        'auction',%s,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''
                        ,'','','','','',0,0,0,0,'',0,'',0,0,0,0,0,0,'',0,0,0,0,%s,%s) """

              query_data =(index['name']+"("+str(index['key'])+")",index['description'][0]+"\n"+index['description'][1],str(index['key']),datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%d"),datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%d"))
              cursor.execute(query, query_data)
              conn.commit()

        conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        json_data_=Get_Json_From_Url()
        Update_Portal(json_data_['server'])
```

With the above code I expect a row is updated if it is in the table and if it does not exist in the table a new row is inserted. For the fist run the update query is not executed and just insert query is executed. And after the first run when the variable `server_data` is the same as before all rows should be updated and no new rows should be inserted. But when I run the code multiple times, it inserts new rows into the table instead of updating!! I commit() after each cursor.execute() to fix this issue but it did not help. I am using mysql.connector, the OS is linux and mysql is running as a docker container. The tables structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblproducts` (
 `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `type` text NOT NULL,
 `gid` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `name` text NOT NULL,
 `description` text NOT NULL,
 `hidden` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `showdomainoptions` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `welcomeemail` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 `stockcontrol` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `qty` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 `proratabilling` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `proratadate` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `proratachargenextmonth` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `paytype` text NOT NULL,
 `allowqty` int(1) NOT NULL,
 `subdomain` text NOT NULL,
 `autosetup` text NOT NULL,
 `servertype` text NOT NULL,
 `servergroup` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `configoption1` text NOT NULL,
 `configoption2` text NOT NULL,
 `configoption3` text NOT NULL,
 `configoption4` text NOT NULL,
 `configoption5` text NOT NULL,
 `configoption6` text NOT NULL,
 `configoption7` text NOT NULL,
 `configoption8` text NOT NULL,
 `configoption9` text NOT NULL,
 `configoption10` text NOT NULL,
 `configoption11` text NOT NULL,
 `configoption12` text NOT NULL,
 `configoption13` text NOT NULL,
 `configoption14` text NOT NULL,
 `configoption15` text NOT NULL,
 `configoption16` text NOT NULL,
 `configoption17` text NOT NULL,
 `configoption18` text NOT NULL,
 `configoption19` text NOT NULL,
 `configoption20` text NOT NULL,
 `configoption21` text NOT NULL,
 `configoption22` text NOT NULL,
 `configoption23` text NOT NULL,
 `configoption24` text NOT NULL,
 `freedomain` text NOT NULL,
 `freedomainpaymentterms` text NOT NULL,
 `freedomaintlds` text NOT NULL,
 `recurringcycles` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `autoterminatedays` int(4) NOT NULL,
 `autoterminateemail` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 `configoptionsupgrade` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `billingcycleupgrade` text NOT NULL,
 `upgradeemail` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 `overagesenabled` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `overagesdisklimit` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `overagesbwlimit` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `overagesdiskprice` decimal(6,4) NOT NULL,
 `overagesbwprice` decimal(6,4) NOT NULL,
 `tax` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `affiliateonetime` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `affiliatepaytype` text NOT NULL,
 `affiliatepayamount` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
 `order` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 `retired` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `is_featured` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `gid` (`gid`),
 KEY `name` (`name`(64))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
```

I changed the column `configoption2` to unique and INT(10). Now with the above code I get the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 377, in cmd_query
    raw_as_string=raw_as_string)
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Duplicate entry '920333' for key 'configoption2'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Update_Hetzner_Auction.py", line 139, in <module>
    Update_Portal(json_data_['server'])
  File "./Update_Hetzner_Auction.py", line 108, in Update_Portal
    cursor.execute(query, query_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 264, in execute
    raw_as_string=self._raw_as_string)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 380, in cmd_query
    sqlstate=exc.sqlstate)
mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError: 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '920333' for key 'configoption2'
```

This error happens when I execute the codes two times immediately. If I run the code and wait for a moment and then run the code, it gets no errors!

Comment: I would advice you to move `conn.commit()` outside the `foor` loop

Comment: at first `con.commit()` was outside of the `for` loop and I know it has better performance. But I thought the issue is because of that so put it after each `execute`. I think it is something related to performance not my issue, right?

Comment: @Sinai: Only English language need to use in your question. Please edit with correct value of "ﺱﺭﻭﺭ ﺎﺨﺘﺻﺎﺻی" in English language.

Comment: I edited my question and removed none English strings.

Comment: @Sinai: please share your table structure and complete program with what exact error \issue occurs.

Comment: I updated my question with full codes. I get no errors. The problem is that when I insert a row with `configoption1='auction'` and a uniqe ID in `configoption2`, after that just update should affects that row. but after executing the code I see multiples row with the same `configoption2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify a field as unique and use insert and on duplicate update as a single query. The statement will insert if the unique field is not there, else it will update the existing.
Reference : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: I changed the field `configoption2` to unique and INT(10). and changed the query as you suggested. It sometimes Updates and sometimes Inserts but because of `ON DUPLICATE KEY` no equal rows are inserted. But the problem is that I need the `id` of the last updated or inserted row. How can I have the last modified row id?

Comment: If a table contains an AUTO_INCREMENT column and INSERT ... UPDATE inserts a row, the LAST_INSERT_ID() function returns the AUTO_INCREMENT value. If the statement updates a row instead, LAST_INSERT_ID() is not meaningful. However, you can work around this by using LAST_INSERT_ID(expr). Suppose that id is the AUTO_INCREMENT column. To make LAST_INSERT_ID() meaningful for updates, insert rows as follows:

Sample: INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id), c=3;

then you can get the last_insert_id to get the id of the latest inserted/updated row.

Comment: simply use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id) which will enable you to get the updated field in last_insert_id. use mysql last insert id to get the same.

Comment: Thank you. I will give it  a try.